# Avoid PDF select with expo-print

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using expo-print on react-native project to generate pdf’s based on html source information.
Because is important information we would like to avoid users to select and copy info and then paste in other places…

so i tried with css but seems not to work.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

i used on html, body, .page and even @page

Can somebody help?